# Sonata Admin Media Picker

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I am using Sonata Admin for my back-end and following [this](https://sonata-project.org/blog/2013/10/11/mediabundle-mediatype-improved) guide I was able to setup a relation between my entities and a media object.

This is the relation:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $image;
```

This is the admin class:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('family')
        ->add('image', MediaType::class, array(
            'provider'  => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
            'context'   => 'default',
            'required'  => false,
        ))
    ;
}
```

These are my settings:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

    # Sonata form themes
    form_themes:
        - 'SonataCoreBundle:Form:colorpicker.html.twig'
        - 'SonataMediaBundle:Form:media_widgets.html.twig'
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I can successfully insert a new image and save it along my entities but **I can't select an entity which already exists**, which settings do i need to get a media picker in a modal window?

Answer (score 1):

To choose any existing media you can use [`sonata_type_model_list`](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html)

Which will show you a field with Add/List options for your model, In your case it will show medias and you can select from the existing medias